# mysql complex query in operation

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the query following:

```
Update `visitors-processed` as t1 
  SET t1.`landedon`="land" 
where t1.`Attributes-ip-date-landedon` in  
  (SELECT distinct t2.`Attributes-ip-date-landedon` 
   from `visitors-processed` as t2 
   group by t2.`Attributes-ip-date-landedon`)
```

It is giving me

> error #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Any suggestions?

Comment: Including '-' in table/column names will drive you insane. At the very least, trying to help further would drive *me* insane.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can get upset when you try to do work on a table and select from that same table in one query. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html). There are ways around this though.

See -

- [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/update-table-based-on-the-same-table?lq=1)
- [here](http://the-stickman.com/uncategorized/mysql-update-with-select-on-the-same-table-in-the-same-query/)

Short answer: this is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The target table can be put in join clause instead of where clause:

```
Update  
    `visitors-processed` t1
inner join
    (select `Attributes-ip-date-landedon`
     from `visitors-processed`
     group by `Attributes-ip-date-landedon` )t2
On t1.`Attributes-ip-date-landedon`=t2.`Attributes-ip-date-landedon`
SET t1.`landedon`='land'
```